# systemd --user not started: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set, but it is

Tags: systemd

`systemd --user` does not work:

```
# systemctl --user status

Failed to read server status: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
```

I have:

```
# echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

/run/user/1000
```

The underlying problem seems to be that `user@1000` is not running. Manually starting produces the same error as by login:

```
# sudo systemctl start user@$(id -u)

Job for user@1000.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status user@1000.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

#systemctl status user@$(id -u)

● user@1000.service - User Manager for UID 1000
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/user@.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Sun 2019-08-18 19:11:41 CEST; 2min 6s ago
     Docs: man:user@.service(5)
  Process: 13047 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 13047 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 452.0K
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service

Aug 18 19:11:41 arch0713 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Aug 18 19:11:41 arch0713 systemd[13047]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user roland by (uid=0)
Aug 18 19:11:41 arch0713 systemd[13047]: Trying to run as user instance, but $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set.
Aug 18 19:11:41 arch0713 systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Aug 18 19:11:41 arch0713 systemd[1]: Failed to start User Manager for UID 1000.
```

The only service failed:

```
# systemctl --failed

  UNIT              LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● user@1000.service loaded failed failed User Manager for UID 1000
```

I have some other Arch installations with basically the same setup, but
the problem is not there. So I seem to have broken just this machine.

Rebooting does not help.

What could I check to find the reason for the error, $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, when `echo` tells me that it is set?

I'm not familiar with the systemd source code, which of course would be a place to look at, and eventually I will, but maybe somebody has a hint for me.

Comment: systemd doesn't start services in the environment of the shell, so the service doesn't see the environment variable `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`. Are you using a login or session manager?

Comment: A login. I don't define XDG_RUNTIME_DIR in any of my scripts, also not in .pam_environment. But it is defined all right immediately after the login. I don't think, it is local to the current shell.

Answer (score 4):

I added some extra log entries (`pam_syslog`) and `journalctl --boot` excerpt is below.

In `pam_systemd.c`

```
453        if (streq_ptr(service, "systemd-user")) {
```

is NOT entered.
It continues afterwards.
The line after `MYISSUEupdate` is executed, but that is after the problematic error entry.

```
   673            r = update_environment(handle, "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR", runtime_path);
```

```
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 login[424]: pam_systemd(login:session): MYISSUE
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 login[424]: pam_systemd(login:session): MYISSUEafter
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 kernel: audit: type=1006 audit(1566740958.028:33): pid=424 uid=0 old-auid=4294967295 auid=1000 tty=tty1 old-ses=4294967295 ses=1 res=1
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 systemd-logind[397]: New session 1 of user roland.
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 1000.
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 systemd[1]: Started User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=user-runtime-dir@1000 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? te>
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1566740958.058:34): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=user-runtime-dir@1000 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/sy>
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 systemd[572]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user roland by (uid=0)
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 systemd[572]: Trying to run as user instance, but $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set.
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1566740958.078:35): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=user@1000 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostn>
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=user@1000 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res>
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 systemd[573]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user roland
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 login[424]: pam_systemd(login:session): MYISSUEafter1
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 systemd[1]: Failed to start User Manager for UID 1000.
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 login[424]: pam_systemd(login:session): MYISSUEafter2
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 systemd[1]: Started Session 1 of user roland.
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 login[424]: pam_systemd(login:session): MYISSUEafter3
    Aug 25 15:49:18 arch0713 login[424]: pam_systemd(login:session): MYISSUEupdate
```

Then I found this [similar issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10574).

I compared

`/etc/pam.d/systemd-user`

```
account include system-auth
session include system-auth
auth required pam_deny.so
password required pam_deny.so
```

of my older problematic installation with the working newer ones.

```
account include system-login
session required pam_loginuid.so
session include system-login
```

Copying this over solved the problem.
It seems like this was not changed by the `pacman -Syu` commands.
I didn't find a [pacnew](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Pacnew_and_Pacsave).